# How to do Sentence Similarity with XLNet?

Tags: python, nlp, embedding, cosine-similarity, transformer-model

I want to perform a sentence similarity task and tried the following:

```
from transformers import XLNetTokenizer, XLNetModel
import torch
import scipy
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

tokenizer = XLNetTokenizer.from_pretrained('xlnet-large-cased')
model = XLNetModel.from_pretrained('xlnet-large-cased')

input_ids = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode("Hello, my animal is cute", add_special_tokens=False)).unsqueeze(0)
outputs = model(input_ids)
last_hidden_states = outputs[0]

input_ids = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode("I like your cat", add_special_tokens=False)).unsqueeze(0) 

outputs1 = model(input_ids)
last_hidden_states1 = outputs1[0]

cos = nn.CosineSimilarity(dim=1, eps=1e-6)
output = cos(last_hidden_states, last_hidden_states1)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (7) must match the size of tensor b (4) at non-singleton dimension 1
```

Can anybody tell me, what I am doing wrong? Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you are doing wrong.

1. `add_special_tokens` should be set to `True`. The model was trained with `<sep>` token for separating sentences and `<cls>` token for sentence classification. Not using the leads to weird behavior because of the train-test data mismatch.
2. `outputs[0]` gives you the first element of a single-member Python tuple. All models from the Transformer package return tuples, therefore this single-member tuple. It contains one vector per input token, including the special ones.
3. Unlike BERT whose `[CLS]` token is the first one, here the `<cls>` token is the very last one (see [Transformers documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/xlnet.html#transformers.XLNetTokenizer.build_inputs_with_special_tokens)). If you want to compare the classification vectors, you should take last vector from the sequence, i.e. `outputs[0][:, -1]`.

Alternatively, you might want to compare the average (mean-pool) of the embedding rather than `<cls>` token embedding. In that case, you can just do `output[0].mean(1)`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried what you suggested and I indeed don't get an error anymore. However, the performance of the network is really bad. When computing the cosine similarity for the sentences:

"My brother plays guitar."
"The sun is shining."

I get a result of 0.93. My code looks like that:

cos = nn.CosineSimilarity(dim=1, eps=1e-6)
output = cos(last_hidden_states, last_hidden_states1)
print(output)